# Difference between 景色 and 見晴らし

Tags: word-choice

Dictionary says both mean 'view', and when I google image both words, more or less the same comes up.  What would the difference be? And if both share the same meaning, which is more common in day to day speech?

Comment: I'm not sure which dictionary you're using, but one means 'scenery', the other means 'view'.

Comment: 景色 - scenery / 見晴らし - view?

Comment: @Daniel yes. Sample sentences from Kenkyūsha: 「見晴らしをよくするために木を切った.　」 vs. 「景色を写生する」。 But 景色 can also be used in the sense of "view", while 見晴らし seems to be more specialized.

Answer (score 2):

景色 focuses on the (beautiful) appearance of nature, whereas 見晴らし focuses on the *wideness* of a view.

景色がいい simply means having a beautiful scenery.

見晴らしがいい means having a wide range of view, blocked by nothing. ここは見晴らしが悪い means you cannot see many things from that point. For example, in military contexts, a lookout post must have a good 見晴らし, but you don't have to be able to enjoy a great 景色.

Answer (score 0):

> yain.jp/i/景色　　景色(けしき)の意味・由来・語源　　 「景色」は平安時代には「気色」と書かれ、人の心の動きや自然の様子を表す語であった。それが鎌倉時代以降、「気色」は人の機嫌・顔色・意向などを表すときは「きそく」や「きしょく」と読まれ、一方、自然界の風景を表すときは ...

I thought maybe 景色 was from Chinese.  I was wrong.  but it's a word that seems more packed with cultural history.

> ｢見晴らしがいい｣　｢眺めがいい｣ 　　　detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1367202823
>   ‎
>   　　　　2011年 ... 一方｢眺めがいい｣は「景色が綺麗」という意味です。 だから｢見晴らしがいい｣は「視界が開けている・遠くまで見える」けど単調な野原しか見えないかも知れない。 一方で｢眺めがいい｣は「視界はそれほど広くない」かも知れないけど、見えている ...

｢見晴らしがいい｣ == You can see long distances (but it could be a boring view).

良い景色 == I think this has more to do with the observer's subjective appreciation of the view.